# Unexpected result in arraylist integer - pde

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, integer, processing

I write a function that sums up the elements of arrays in a 2d list and add them in a 1d list:

```
  ArrayList<Integer> sumList(ArrayList<int[][]> list,int side){
    ArrayList<Integer> sums= new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for(int[][] array : list){
    int arraySum = 0;
    //arraySum += CalcMove(array,side);
      for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++){
          for(int j = 0; j < 8; j++){
            arraySum+=array[i][j];
          }
      }
      sums.add(arraySum);
      //println(arraySum);
    }
    println(sums);
    //sums.add(0);
    //println(sums);
    return sums;
  }
```

The problem is, the result are totally irrelevant,ambiguous and not even in a list. The println result:

> [-232, -232, -232]
>   -232 [-232, -232, -232]
>   -232 [-223, -223, -223]
>   -223 [-223, -223, -223, -223]
>   -223 [-219, -219, -219]
>   -219 [-214, -214, -214]
>   -214 [-14, -14, -14]
>   -14 [-10, -10, -10]
>   -10 [-5, -5, -5]
>   -5 [-4, -4, -4, -4]
>   -4 [-4, -4, -4, -4]
>   -4 [-4, -4, -4, -4]
>   -4 [-4, -4, -4, -4]
>   -4 [-4, -4, -4, -4]
>   -4 [-4, -4, -4, -4, -4, -4, -4, -4, -4, -4, -4, -4, -4, -4]
>   -4 []

But when I add another element outside the loops (in this case it's zero), the result will be OK (I'm still not sure it is). the println result after this:

> [-232, -232, -232, 0]

I'm totally confused about this since I'm pretty sure the function does not have any problem cause I tested individually and it's worked just fine. And it couldn't be the arraylist cause I wrote the entire project in c# and it's worked just fine, too.

Comment: What is the size of the list you're passing?

Comment: @NirajPatel Each time is different. it's depend on decision trees.

Comment: Do you have multiple threads running by any chance? Ideally, provide a [mcve] demonstrating the problem...

Comment: @JonSkeet No I don't think so. I'm sorry but I don't know how to explain the problem in a better way. I'm open for any suggestion.

Comment: Well you could try providing a [mcve] as I mentioned before. If we can reproduce it, I'm sure we can solve it. (It's not clear what the commented out lines in your code are about. Are you sure they were still commented out when you ran the code and produced that output?)

Comment: what number 8 does mean in your loops?

Comment: Please post a [mcve] that we can copy and paste to run ourselves. Specifically, you need to hard-code some input and call this function. If we can't see your input, it's going to be pretty hard to help you.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a method that collects all integer in a 2d array and put them into a list.

```
    public static List<Integer> listElements(int[][] array) {
        List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        for (int[] subArray : array) {
            IntStream.of(subArray).forEach(i -> list.add(i));
        }
        return list;
    }
```